# user select folder for download from browser using angular/jQuery

Tags: jquery, angular, browser, directory, download

I want to browse and select folder for download excel from browser

User dynamically select the folder for download excel

I tried with

```
<input id="input-folder-1" type="file" webkitdirectory>
```

but upload the files inside the folder.

but I want to select folder.

Thanks Advance !!!

Comment: File input that you have here is for uploading TO the website, not downloading files FROM it. Typically the user's browser will download to the pre-configured Downloads folder.

Comment: @Ortund Okay, can we select the folder from browser using angular ? anyother option?